# How to properly deploy Azure Logic Apps via ARM with connected resources?

Tags: deployment, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Sorry if my question is trivial but I am newbie in DevOps.

I want to design smooth pipeline to deploy LogicApps along with ServiceBus and AzureStorage. Developers commit the code and it should ideally automatically deploy to Azure after each commit.

I know that Visual Studio generate ARM template for LogicApps. So when developers going to write their LogicApps it will automatically have ARM templates for deployment.

However what about connected resources? Should I ask them to write ARM templates to create ServiceBus & AzureStorage too?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the ServiceBus & AzureStorage in one ARM template (if you have these resources made in the portal already, you can just extract them, see "Export template" on the selected resource)

then I would [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates) to the logic app ARM template, extracting logic apps with [this](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator) is recommended